# What battery should I use in a remote control for a score marker?

Tags: batteries

I need help in choosing the right battery for my project.
I built a ping pong score marker for my school two years ago.
It is separated in two parts:

1. The score marker. It has the displays, an Arduino Mega and the drivers for the displays.
2. The control. It has the buttons to reset, go to the next set, and add or deduct a point to each player.

**The control is connected to the score marker with a Ethernet cable.**

Now I want to improve it by making the control wireless.

I need a battery that hold the charge for long periods of time.
The batteries only need to provide 45 mA at most.

I'm thinking to choose the 18650. Is it the right choice, or should I go for a LiPo, those that are commonly used in RC airplanes?

Comment: Define a long period of time? 20 weeks or 50 years?

Comment: Have you considered using BlueTooth instead of Wi-Fi to save on the energy consumption?

Comment: This question is not specific enough to be answerable at present.  To do something like this properly, you need to first figure out the type of sensing required and the nature of the information to be communicated.  Then you decide if it can go into an active mode on its own, or if users have to turn it on (and maybe back off again), etc.  With good design you can probably use an MCU and a 2.4 GHz packet radio (either as distinct parts or in the form of a BLE chip that can do other 2.4 GHz modes) and run it off a coin cell.  But your *unspecified* sensors might require too much power for that.

Comment: @SolarMike With two 18650 (6000mAh in total) it can last for more than a month. If the battery self-discharge is 15%/month a significant part of the energy will be lost.

Comment: @LewisMojica as your matches are less than 24hrs, the batteries can be recharged overnight... But if they can be recharged then a 15% loss should not affect the operating period - as long as you don't forget to charge them...

Comment: Your edit doesn't really help things at all, except to call into question why you want to use batteries and wireless in something that has wires coming out of it already.  Why not use some POE-like scheme?

Comment: @AndrewMorton maybe you miss understood me. It is connected through a **Ethernet cable** not wifi. I'm going to use the NRF24L01 module

Comment: @LewisMojica the problem is that you posted an **unanswerably incomplete** question.

Comment: @LewisMojica I thought that by "wireless" you meant with no wires at all, so the Ethernet cable would have to be replaced with some wireless technology.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, at first I wrote "through Ethernet" but now I fixed it and says "through a Ethernet cable"

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'll try to add more useful information

Comment: @SolarMike The less often the battery has to be charged the better. It easier for the user and the battery life extends.

Comment: If you do this *right* a coin cell should be sufficient for years.  If you do it *wrong*, you'll run a car battery down in less than a week.  Your question as asked is pointless; what you should be focusing on is how to build a suitable radio system that only consumes power when a button is held, not what sort of battery to power that with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The battery choice depends on how you intend to implement the wireless communication between the control unit and the score marker.
There are several options you can opt for, but you are mostly limited by the range you require.

It is clear that you will only need to transmit to the score market only when you press a button, therefore the controller can go into a sleep or deep sleep mode in the meanwhile, extending quite considerably the battery life.
Here are a few options:

- The simplest solution is ag ate opener remote running at 433MHz which usually have 4 buttons. These remotes usually run on a CR2032, which will last years, It is extremely cheap, you can potentially hack one of these if 4 buttons are enough.
- NRF24L01 - it uses 2.4GHz frequency, and it can be quite good low power mode but you will need another MCU to manage the buttons, data to transmit, and power management. Even with that, a good AA battery would work for a good part of a year, as long as you manage smartly the sleep modes.
  The  datasheet of the NRF24L01 states at page 21 that the current consumption is 900 nA in Power Down more and 26 uA in Standby. If you use an Arduino Pro mini, with the appropriate modifications (such as removing the LED), you can take the current consumption as well in the uA range.
- I would avoid WiFi and Bluetooth, as they introduce a lot of unnecessary complications in a project that requires a low bandwidth and some range.

If you are keen on using rechargeable batteries, then you can use them, but I would stay away from 18650 because they are rather bulky for a remote. I would rather go for smaller ones in a rectangular form factor, such as the ones they use for flying small drones, which have a capacity of 500-1000mAh. These batteries are still overkill, but can work, as long as you choose a type with a low self discharge rate.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The unit control has six buttons, so the gate opener is not an option. I'll go for the NRF24L01. I'll make the unit control and measure the power consumption, depending on the results I'll use the LiPo or AA batteries.

Comment: If your current draw is in the mA and you don't want an on/off switch, neither will give you acceptably long battery life.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to be a bit more specific in defining what your battery needs to do.

Battery power devices can "last a long time" in a couple of different ways.

They can go to "sleep" and draw very little power for huge spans of time, and only wake up for a few milliseconds to do stuff. TV remotes are an example of this. They can last a year or more on one small battery.

Some devices on the other hand are always doing stuff, like your score display. You can try to make these as efficient as possible, but ultimately they're going to be drawing at least a few mA all the time, so the lifespan is going to be measured in hours, not months.

It *sounds* like you want to make a battery powered remote control. So it's like the first example.

The key to these devices is not the size of the battery, but how well they sleep. You can make this device run for years off a few coin cells if you design it right.

Here's what you have to do:

1. Make the device go to sleep, and only wake up ~10 times per second do see if a button has been pressed.
2. Stay awake for as short a time as you possibly can.
3. Adjust the microcontroller settings so EVERYTHING not essential is turned off. Analog to digital converters, watchdog timers, all that stuff.
4. Tweak the circuit so that it draws very little current when it's not doing anything. You want to get it to be less than 10uA. As a rule of thumb, the more "stuff" you have powered, the more the current draw will be when idle. Ideally you just want your micro powered, and nothing else.

Ok, that's the professional solution. But what about some *other* solutions.

- Take apart an IR remote control, and wire your buttons onto that. Then all you have to do is build an IR receiver for your display, and that's pretty easy.
- Give the remote a physical on/off switch, and just use a couple of AA's or C/D cells. This way even 24 hours of battery life will last you a long while. Make sure to put an LED on it or something so people don't leave it on.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The IR solution is not convenient. I think the NRF24L01 is a better option, because using it  the remote control doesn't need to have a clear vision line to the score board.

Comment: I'll use an Arduino nano or a pro mini. I can wake up the MCU with an interrupt (caused by the buttons), so it does't has to wake up that often.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what you use for communication if you create your own low power design, since you'll switch all that off except when a button is pushed. Watch you quiescent currents. A lot of devices have useful shutdown modes, but some dont.